# Masking specific hour periods on week days in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, time-series

I have a [pandas.Dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), it looks like this:

```
                            A
date                            
2017-07-22 04:30:00  2707.500000
2017-07-22 05:00:00  2715.400000
2017-07-22 05:30:00  2759.300000
2017-07-22 06:00:00  2755.079086
2017-07-22 08:30:00  2840.000000
2017-07-22 09:00:00  2817.500000
2017-07-22 09:30:00  2818.900000
2017-07-22 10:00:00  2838.300000
2017-07-22 10:30:00  2865.300000
2017-07-22 11:00:00  2888.800000
...                          ...
...                          ...
2017-08-03 11:30:00  2742.000000
2017-08-03 12:00:00  2737.000000
2017-08-03 12:30:00  2732.000000
2017-08-03 13:00:00  2738.000000
2017-08-03 13:30:00  2742.800000
2017-08-03 14:00:00  2736.900000
2017-08-03 14:30:00  2733.300000
2017-08-03 15:00:00  2739.400000
```

..etc

What i'm trying to do is create mask that selects all rows where date is both a week day and hours are within [X] and [Y].

Example:

```
mask = SELECT ROWS where Date is a Weekday and Hour is greater than 9am and less than 5pm
```

My thinking has been something like:

```
newdf = df.apply(lambda x : np.where(pd.date_range(??, ??).weekday), axis=1)
```

I've also seen reference to some '[isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)' function..

Over all I am very stuck on this and not finding much suitable via googling. Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [1140]: (df.index.hour >= 9) & (df.index.hour <= 17) & (df.index.weekday < 5)
Out[1140]:
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [1141]: df[(df.index.hour >= 9) & (df.index.hour <= 17) & (df.index.weekday < 5)]
Out[1141]:
                          A
date
2017-08-03 11:30:00  2742.0
2017-08-03 12:00:00  2737.0
2017-08-03 12:30:00  2732.0
2017-08-03 13:00:00  2738.0
2017-08-03 13:30:00  2742.8
2017-08-03 14:00:00  2736.9
2017-08-03 14:30:00  2733.3
2017-08-03 15:00:00  2739.4
```

And, if your data doesn't need weekday check, for time filtering, you could use `between_time`

```
In [1144]: df.between_time('9:00AM', '5:00PM')
Out[1144]:
                          A
date
2017-07-22 09:00:00  2817.5
2017-07-22 09:30:00  2818.9
2017-07-22 10:00:00  2838.3
2017-07-22 10:30:00  2865.3
2017-07-22 11:00:00  2888.8
2017-08-03 11:30:00  2742.0
2017-08-03 12:00:00  2737.0
2017-08-03 12:30:00  2732.0
2017-08-03 13:00:00  2738.0
2017-08-03 13:30:00  2742.8
2017-08-03 14:00:00  2736.9
2017-08-03 14:30:00  2733.3
2017-08-03 15:00:00  2739.4
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. So simple. Amazing when you don't know how. Thanks for taking the time to answer this for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: After thought: What if i want to find data between 11pm and 3am the following morning.. ensuring both dates are within a weekday..